# install remote desktop in a PC with FTP and HTTP access

Tags: remote-desktop, ftp, java, vnc, http

I have a machine behind a firewall to which I have only FTP and HTTP access - is there any remote desktop software available that I can install over FTP and access over HTTP (java based perhaps)?

The reason I'm asking is because ultraVNC stopped working for no reason and I need to access the PC (it has installed windows 7 with UAC disabled).

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can put up the java page for VNC.

http://www.tightvnc.com/download.html
I used this one: `Java viewer source in ZIP archive`.
1) Download it to your machine.
2) Unpack it.
3) Upload the file into a place where you can access it from http (so upload it to your remote machine)
4) Open it in your browser (from the computer where you are now).
5) Try logging in through this interface.

(ps.: You need [Java Runtime Environment](http://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp) on your PC for this.)

(Can't see any other workarounds for this. Can't you issue a remote restart? RDP connection?)

Comment: i get a class not found error (error log below) - any ideas?

load: class VncViewer.class not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: VncViewer.class
(...)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: open HTTP connection failed: http://myhostip/vnc_javasrc/VncViewer/class.class
(...)
Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: VncViewer.class

Comment: I doubt this will help, as it's just the client one would be installing then. (One could install that client on *any* server, and I doubt using a local client to be able to connect to localhost will solve the issue). The question about installing (or somehow restarting) the VNC server, right, @user?

Comment: Arjan, yes you're right

Comment: @user39: Well, it helped me out. Then no way it could work, no other idea from me, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

To do that i'd suggest to try OnlineVNC - http://www.onlinevnc.com/support/configuring-ftp-based-file-transfer.html

It is a remote desktop solution with FTP file transfer engine inside. Can work in WebBrowser and absolutely free.